# Why is the "Use default value from package" option disabled?

Tags: ssis-2012

I've got a SSIS project deployed to SQL-Server 2012. When I go to configure the *project*, the only option I have to set any of the parameter values is **Edit value**. The **Use default value from package** is disabled. I can understand why this might be the case for project level parameters, but I'd expect that package level parameters would could use the default values. What controls this?

Answer (score 5):

This is because your parameter would be marked as required. The Microsoft site states "When a parameter is marked as required, a server value or execution value must be specified for that parameter. Otherwise, the corresponding package does not execute. Although the parameter has a default value at design time, it will never be used once the project is deployed."

I have no idea why the SSIS team made this design call. I guess it's to force developers to manually go through each required parameter once the project is deployed. Painful if you ask me.